# what's the best interface for managing very large numbers of files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have requirement to write in .net UI similar to win file explorer for managing very large number of virtual files (thousands). There will be file names, location and some metadata for each. All probably will be getting from some sql database. 
I have some concerns with file explorer solution, especially with searching performance.  Trying to use now telerik radfileExplorer control, search is implemented there only in current folder because of performance. My worries are when I add recursive search for thousand of files it will last long time.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FileTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx) in SQL Server to store files. File table works on filestream technology and works faster on file search. It has Windows API compatibility for file data stored within an SQL Server database. You can traverse and search files in file table via TSQL statements.

The major advantage of using file table is that data is not stored on database but on file system. You are also allowed to modify data via windows explorer.